# Is the current screen resolution saved to a file anywhere?

Tags: x11, xrandr, resolution

I'm trying to do a low level set of functions to get and set the display resolution, and I was wondering if there was a file that contains only the used resolution and that could be used to change it.

I know I could find part of what I'm looking for in the Xorg settings file but it contains more than just the active resolution.

So far, everything I found requiered using Xorg or `xrandr` and I hope to find a way to do this by only reading/writing in a file.

Comment: What's not good with using `xrandr`?

Comment: @pfnuesel Having to do a system call. In case one day I have to switch environment and it doesn't have `xrandr`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The current resolution is stored in the memory of the X server. It is not stored in a file.

The Xorg settings file won't help you since it only contains the initial configuration (and may not exist at all), but the resolution can be called dynamically.

(I think the resolution actually appears in the X server logs, but you aren't guaranteed to have access to the logs — for example if you're accessing the server remotely — and even if you do you'd have to parse the logs which is a lot of work and error-prone.)

Call `xrandr`. That's what it's for. You shouldn't need to worry about environments without it: it's a basic tool, part of the standard X11 client distribution.

In case you need to run on ancient systems that predate `xrandr` (it's only 15 years old), you can call `xdpyinfo`, which has been part of the standard X11 client distribution for over two decades.

Answer (score 0):

So, after trying the previous answers, I was convinced but not entierly satisfied. I continued my research a bit and finally found what I was looking for. There is actually a file containing the resolution of the screen, along with another containing all the resolutions supported by the screen, those provided by its EDID.

Those files can be found in `/sys/class/graphics` and then in the directory corresponding to your framebuffer (usually fb0). The files of interest are called `mode` (containing the current resolution) and `modes` (containing every resolution supported by the screen).

To change the resolution, one muste do :  `echo your-resolution > mode`, where `your-resolution` is exactly one of the line of the files `modes`.

Here is a concrete example to illustrate. I want to set my resolution to the VESA standard. The allowed resolutions for my screen are defined as follow :

```
# cat modes
D:1920x1080p-60
S:1280x720p-50
S:1280x720p-60
S:1920x1080p-50
S:1920x1080p-60
S:640x480p-60
S:720x480p-60
S:720x576p-50
V:640x480p-60
```

All I need to do is `echo V:640x480p-60 > mode` and my screen resolution becomes 640x480.